# Which directory to put website code inside Openshift github repository

Tags: django, git, python-3.x, openshift

- Created an Openshift application, named 'app'.
- Cloned 'app''s git repo on to my computer.

There's .git, .openshift, app, etc. directories inside that local repo.

Now where do I place my website code?
In which folder?